# How to set binding options in wpf DataGridCells that are auto generated?

Tags: wpf, data-annotations, wpfdatagrid, idataerrorinfo, datagridcell

I use `IDataErrorInfo` and `DataAnnotations` in my `ViewModels` to take care of validation and I want to use them for validation in my `DataGrid`. The behaviour I want for my cells can be simulated easily in a `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Name="TestBox"
    Text="{Binding TextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

However, in my `DataGrid`, the columns are automatically generated, and I can't set the `ValidatesOnDataErrors` binding option as I could if they were defined manually.

What I would like to do is something along these lines in a Style, since I don't want to alter the Binding's value, only its Binding Options:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
</Style>
```

But this doesn't work. I am not sure what Property to use in the setter, as the `DataGridCell` has an internal `TextBox` or `TextBlock`, and what exactly handles the cell's validation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your datagrid, hook the "AutoGeneratingColumn" event.

Inside the event handler, you can use e.Column to get to the binding and adjust it. You'll have to cast e.Column to the correct type first though (DataGridTextColumn, for example).

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dg" AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dg.ItemsSource = new List<MyItem>() { new MyItem() { Item1 = "Item 1", Item2 = "Item 2" } };
    }

    private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var tc = e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn;
        var b = tc.Binding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;

        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        b.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        b.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it seemed to have no effect. Note that the datagrid validates by default on inputs it can't cast (an error is shown when you enter a string in a field expecting an int). But it doesn't apply validation on DataAnnotations like [Range(0,255)]